# Trying to solve an approximation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm really stumped on this, I am essentially creating a program that gives you your location (City,State) based on latitudes and longitudes. I have hundredth of radius's in the database. If I have a coordinate of **(31.424141,-82.017859)** I would like to grab the closest latitude and longitude to that. I have 4 fields in the query *South_Latitude, North_Latitude, East_Longitude, West_Longitude*. The latitude falls inside **South_Latitude, North_Latitude** and the longitude falls inside **East_Longitude, West_Longitude**  .For instance this example

```
select top 1 * from zipsmee 
  where 31.424141 >= South_Latitude 
  AND North_Latitude>= 31.424141 
  AND -82.017859 >=East_Longitude 
  AND West_Longitude>=-82.017859 
  order by city ASC
```

The problem with the query above is that if a given latitude,longitude fall's outside of the range the results come back NULL and instead of coming back null I want the closest record/row nearest to the given latitude,longitude

**Update**

The query above has some conditional statements so if it falls outside of that condition it will give me a null. I will check for that and in the event that I get a null the program will go to a second query and in this second query I would like to get the row/record where the latitude,longitude is closest to **South_Latitude, North_Latitude, East_Longitude, West_Longitude** . As soon as I get off of work I will post some pictures if that helps.

Comment: because of AND conditions in where filters is giving back you NULLS.post some sample data

Comment: I will as soon as I get home, I will update my post.

Comment: Can you use spatial data types? MSDN [covers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff929109.aspx) this topic very well

Comment: Yes I can use spatial types thanks for the link I will read over it.

Comment: For finding closest distance you need to calculate distance then use `Top(1) ... ORDER BY ABS(distance)` ;).

Comment: You just want the closest point? I second the recommendation to use the geography type.